# Trying to loop through a specific column inside a table and capture highest value

Tags: jquery, html-table

http://jsfiddle.net/dweiliu/bcHsy/2/

I've been at this for some time and I'm missing something...

Relevant block of jQuery.

```
$('article.weeklyStandings').each(function(){
    var winningPercentage = $('tr.record:nth-of-type(2)',this).find('td:nth-of-type(4)');
    $('tr.record',this).each(function(){
        var percentageWon = $(this).find('td:nth-of-type(4)');
        if (percentageWon == winningPercentage) {
            $('td:nth-of-type(1)', this).html("winner");
        }
    });
});
```

Context available in jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/dweiliu/bcHsy/2/

I have a table with some results in column 4. I want to go through every row in the column and compare the value to the 2nd row. If it is == to that value, I want to do something.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: IT is working as you want ...???

Comment: No it is not. I calculate winningPercentage first. I then loop through the rows and calculate percentageWon. Ideally, if it matches, I do something, once it becomes less than the winningPercentage, I do something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try comparing the `text()` value of the result of the two jquery selectors you have executed.  So, change this line:

`if (percentageWon == winningPercentage)`

to read:

`if (percentageWon.text() == winningPercentage.text())`

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yup, this was my problem. Thanks! I take it this is because the number + "%" means the variables I am comparing are no longer numbers.

Comment: I think you will find that the inital (problematic) comparison is comparing the result of your selectors, which are jQuery objects, so while the code looks like you are comparing their (string) values you are really comparing their 'identities' which are not the same.  Look at the sub topic __jQuery Object Type__ in this glossary http://learnjavascript.co.uk/jq/pages/jqglossary.html which might help to explain a little better.

Comment: Thanks. I knew that it became an object but since I'm relatively new to js/jQuery, I didn't know to use .text(). Now I do! As an aside, I have a few other things going on in my js file, is there a place where I can post a more substantial block of code (it's really only 30 lines) and see if people have suggestions on how to make it more efficient?

Comment: @Dave I have not spent much time there, but you might want to check out: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for that purpose.  More info: http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/138/how-is-this-site-different-from-stackoverflow and http://codereview.stackexchange.com/about

Answer (score 0):

Try this one out, it is a bit more efficient since it buffers elements and it requires only one iteration

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var count = 0;
    var container = $('article.weeklyStandings'); // buffer the container
    var records = container.find('tr.record'); // buffer the winnin records
    var winner = 0;

    records.each(function() {
        var cells = $(this).children('td');
        // use text() and trim so extra space do not break the number conversion
        var gamesWon = parseInt(cells.eq(1).text().trim()); 
        var gamesPlayed = parseInt(cells.eq(2).text().trim());                  
        var percentage = (gamesWon / gamesPlayed * 100).toFixed(1);                 

        // save the percentage so it could be selected
        cells.eq(3).attr("wining-percent", percentage).text(percentage + "%");

        // add to the players count
        count++;
        if (percentage >= winner)
            winner = percentage; 
    });

    // write the amount of players
    container.find("h2").append(" - " + count + " Players");                
    // now add the winning class to the winners
    records.find('td[wining-percent="' + winner + '"]').parent().addClass("winner");
});
```

I would recommend to process info to bring JSON from the server instead of picking values from the DOM.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I actually have a slightly more complex website which includes multiple articles within multiple sections. The way your example code loops through the records doesn't account for that. I will eventually be able to move this data over to something like JSON.